# "bash: gcc: command not found" -- Error while installing GCC, GDB and G++ with MSYS2

Tags: windows, gcc, g++, mingw, msys2

I'm using [that](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_prerequisites) instruction to install MinGW, but face a problem on checking versions. The error that occuries after `$ gcc --version` looks like `bash: gcc: command not found`

I've already checked my environment variables `Path` (both User and System). The piece that I added to `Path` was `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin;`. Without any `""` and with `;`, as you can see. Also I checked `bin` folder and `gcc` and other files were there.

What could be the problem?

Comment: What command did you use to install GCC? What is written in the terminal prompt in magenta letters, `MSYS` or `MINGW64` or what?

Comment: `$ pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc` that's the one I used. In magenta letters is `MSYS`

Comment: The command is ok. But note that it installs to `C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin`, not `mingw64`. The magenta text is wrong, for this package it must say `UCRT64`. How did you launch MSYS2 bash?

Comment: Oh, you are right, I reinstalled MSYS2 from official installation page and now it works! Thank you!

Comment: FYI, MSYS2 has several shortcuts for starting those different shells. There's one for UCRT64, one for MSYS, etc. More info: https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the environment variable path as **C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin** in case if you have installed gcc using **pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc**.

OR

You can install gcc using:
**pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc** and set environment variable path as **C:\msys64\mingw64\bin**.